# RStudio Required Package Versions Could Not Be Found

Tags: r, rstudio

I updated my Mac to OS10 and attempting to run RStudio Knit, and get the error:

```
"evaluate 0.7.2 is required but 0.7 is available".
```

I tried this and did not fixed the issue:

```
remove.packages("evaluate")
install.packages("evaluate")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've got `0.9` from the RStudio mirror. Update?

Comment: i'm using version 0.99

Comment: What version of RStudio are you using?

Answer (score 8):

Try setting up the below option and by rerunning the code.

```
getOption("repos")
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.rstudio.org"))
```

Comment: Why this isn't available in the gui is beyond me.  It should be.

Answer (score 4):

It also happened to me. I downloaded evaluate zip file from here https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/evaluate/index.html 
and then manually installed it in R Studio (Tools-InstallPackages-zip file).
Good luck !

Comment: Can you post the instructions here instead of just linking to it?

Comment: 1) First download zip file  evaluate_0.9.zip, from the link above and store it somewhere on your computer

Comment: 2) In RStudio under Tools, click InstallPackages and there you will have an option to choose a zip file from your computer

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages('evaluate')
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository HTTP://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4:
  cannot open URL 'HTTP://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES'
```

When you compile the update or remove sentences, if the output like this, you could make some settings, since maybe the problem is your internet. Follow the steps:

1. Open Rstudio.
2. Click tools.
3. Choose global options->packages.
4. Modify CRAN to the country you living. like, China or Japan. Cause your browser maybe work only you do this.